# Selecting JavaScript drowndown option causes D3 treemap to change

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a D3 treemap and would like to include a dropdown using javascript in a seperate `<div>` tag. For some reason when an option is selected, the D3 treemap changes.

I have been racking my brain trying to figure it out, but haven't had any luck.

I put it all together in a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2jar30c2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change in treemap is due to this line:

```
treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
```

this.value is equal to `Option 1` or `Option 2` so this line sets the value accessor count function:

```
function count(d) {
    return 1;
}
```

The size of the tiles in treemap depends on this value. There was set this function as value accessor before:

```
function(d) {
    return d.size;
}
```

It returns the `size` attribute which is defined in the JSON and it contains different values than count accessor returns (count returns `1` for each node).